# Correct way to build debian using Cmake and catkin?

Tags: cmake, debian, ros, cpack, catkin

I'm trying to build a debian using CMake/Cpack but am running into an issue. The problem is that I am getting unwanted files in my debian. It is caused by including a subdirectory, which contains a CMakeLists.txt that invokes catkin commands for ROS msg generation.

If I look at the contents of the debian I see generated header files in /usr/include/ and message files in /usr/share. But I only want my debian to have the files in /opt/bin which I specified using install().

Below is a simplified example. If I run the following commands:

- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake ..
- make
- cpack

The result is a deb package containing /opt/my-pkg/bin/main (which is great), but it also contains several files in /usr/local, /usr/lib, /usr/share that I don't want to be in the debian. I'm sure there must be a way using CMake/CPack to only create a debian with the specific files I want, but I'm not sure how to do it.

**FILE TREE**

```
+ my_project
  + CMakeLists.txt
  + main
    + CMakeLists.txt
    + main.cpp
  + my_msgs
    + CMakeLists.txt
    + package.xml
    + msg
      + BoundingBox.msg
```

```
# Top level CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)
project(my_project VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# put all executables into bin directory and all libraries into lib directory
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

# the directory name all targets will be installed to in the debian
set(install_dir "/opt/my-pkg/bin") 

# LIST OF ALL DIRECTORIES TO BE BUILT
set(DIRS 
  my_msgs
  main
 )

foreach(dir ${DIRS})
  add_subdirectory(${dir} ${dir})
endforeach()

# CPACK debian settings
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Matthew Mosley")
include(CPack)
```

```
# my_msgs/CMakeLists.txt (this is the CMakeLists.txt that is generating extra unwanted files in my debian)

project(my_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED 
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  )

add_message_files(FILES BoundingBox.msg)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  geometry_msgs
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs)
```

```
# my_msgs/package.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>my_msgs</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description> my_msgs package</description>


  <license>BSD</license>


     <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

     <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend> 

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>uuid_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>uuid_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>

  <export>


  </export>
</package>
```

Comment: Do you mean a deb package?  Also, we're gonna need some sample code (at minimum, your CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Thanks, I added more detail to my question and some CMakeLists.txt files